# .htaccess URL and resources

Tags: .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I have the next url:
www.dude12345.com/section.php?id=5

I want to be like this www.dude12345.com/section/5

I used the next code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/section\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /section/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/section.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^section/([0-9]+)$ /section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It works..my link it looks how i want (www.dude12345.com/section/5). 
But i have a problem my resources are not loaded good. In console appear something like: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) www.dude12345/section/images/myimg.png " and it's not ok, need to apear someting like www.dude12345/images/myimg.png. I have no idea how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it is working fine for me.
Just make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?section/([^/d]+)/?$ section.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: can you please post the url and it is not working. Actually I tested like this way: www.example.com/section.php?id=2 To www.example.com/section/2 And it is working fine.

Comment: I solved, the problem was the links of the resource. I didn't know about the difference between absolute and relative links. Thank you for help!